# B2B Payments through Blockchain Technology

Tags: enterprise

what does it take for a large enterprise to shift from regular bank payments methods to Ethereum payments. How will it impact their supplies?

Comment: Welcome!  Your question is probably too broad, try https://www.scribd.com/doc/314477721/Ethereum-Platform-Review-Opportunities-and-Challenges-for-Private-and-Consortium-Blockchains and then edit your question to be more specific.